# How to give a Linux user permission to create backups, but not permission to delete them?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions, virus

I want to set up automated backups that are kept safe from myself (in case a virus pwns me). The problem is the "create" and "delete" permissions are the same thing: write permission. So what can I do about it? Is it possible to decouple the create/delete permissions?

Another option could be to let the user "root" make the backups. The problem is my home directory is encrypted, and I don't want to backup everything.

Any ideas?

For the backups I'm using Deja Dup, which is installed by default in Fedora and Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you heard of extended attributes on ext filesystems? `man chattr` maybe shows you some hints for a solution, i. e. there's the so called immuteable bit (+i) which denys the deletion of files.

Comment: Backup to write-once media (cd-r,dvd-r).  Take a strong look at write-once filesystems.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another user account on your machine (or use root like you mention?). Then your backup does something like this:

- Copies your files to a location where both of you have read/write
  access
- The other users account has some kind of automated process
  (cron?) that then moves these files to a location where it has
  read/write access but you only have read access